# How is total stack size required by a function and variable scope related?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm getting a stack overflow in my program being compiled with Visual Studio 2010.  I have a macro that, within a do-while block, does some string related work using a small char array allocated on stack (8 KiB).  I then have a function where I use this macro many times in the same scope.  And now I'm getting stack overflows.

I was assuming that the stack allocation was local to the do-while block, and thus when the block ended the array would cease to exist and thus not contribute to the overall stack usage of the function, but it appears I was wrong.

Using the debugger I was able to see that upon entering the function, _chkstk() is called.  As an argument to this function is a stack size slightly larger than the sum of all the 8 KiB arrays from each invocation of the macro in that function (slightly larger due to other local variables).

I have recreated the problem using a simple example:

```
void func(void)
{
    {char a[500000];}
    {char b[500000];}
    {char c[500000];}
    {char d[500000];}
    {char e[500000];}
}
```

In a simple console application calling this function from main() will result in a stack overflow.  Removing all but one of the block statements will however run just fine.

I am wondering if this is working as intended?

How is total stack size required by a function calculated?
How is stack size required by a function calculated?
Arrays on stack still contribute to total stack size of function, even after going out of scope?

Why am I getting a stack overflow when

Comment: You can't reuse the memory for variables in nested blocks because of aliasing: http://ideone.com/z9HQUU

Comment: @millimoose That is undefined behavior, hence it is irrelevant since the compiler can optimize it all out.

Comment: The C standard *allows* a compiler to recycle the stack space for large allocations that are scoped to one block within a function, but it does not *require* it. Reusing stack space within a function turns out to be harder than you would think, so a lot of compilers don't do it.  However, I'm a little surprised VS2010 doesn't do it, because it's very good at inlining, and you need to reuse stack space to do aggressive inlining well.  Are you sure you turned on all the optimization?

Comment: @rightfold You're right, after working more on the example it turns out the space *can be* reused: http://ideone.com/rnFYp4. My bad.

Comment: Having a macro that does _"string related work"_ relying on stack `char` array in C++ really smells like a bad design decision in the first place. You'd rather go with dynamic allocation for that, and using `std::string` is good to abstract away from all these problems altogether.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that the standard doesn't define exactly how much space on the stack (or indeed that they are stored on the stack) these variables require. The compiler is certainly not required to NOT allocate a space for each of these local variables. The actual reuse may also be highy dependent on the optimization levels of the compiler - so it may do different things if you compile with different levels of optimization (or if you enable/disable certain optimization features).

In C++, the calls to constructors and destructors are defined for blocks which enclose the variable, so if you were to use `std::vector`, the memory (allocated from the heap) is released when the block ends.

In summary: The space MAY be reused, but it's by no means guaranteed.

Comment: `std::vector` allocates memory for its elements at heap, not at the stack. So it will not lead to stack overflow anyway.

Comment: @Inspired: Yes, I have just edited to clarify that, but I didn't mean that stack space is reused, just that "whatever happens in the constructor is undone by the destructor, which both happens within the set of braces that enclose the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is compiler-specific. The same works fine with GCC: the arrays are removed from stack after going out of scope (but it throws segfault when all arrays belong to the same block).